# Fixing scrolling performance with fixed background image on div

Tags: html, css, performance, scroll, background

I am trying to fix scrolling preformance problems on my site.  I have a few div elements with `background-size: cover` and `background-attachment: fixed`.  As I understand these are pretty gpu intensive.  I am trying to fix the problem by making the background images a separate layer on the div.

I found this site that demonstates how to do this, but I am confused by what they have done.  What is `@include clearfix;`? How can I implement this on my site?

https://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property

I have attached the code from a div element on my site which I hope to optimize.

Also, here is the url to my site (its a work in progress but you can see how there is scrolling issues).

http://petermankiewich.com/

Thank you for your input!

```css
.imagediv1 {
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  max-height: 1500px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-position: bottom center !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagediv1" style="background:url(Images/workstationpic.jpg)"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change the Position property to relative and check if it works for you.

```
.frontCover{position: relative;}
```

Comment: do you mean in the handwritting.css file?

Comment: Yes, include your own css file with the name style.css and place it in HTML under the already present css file link. update above given css and it will override the effect. Please let me know if you need more help. Thanks