# Ideas on improving scrolling performance on my site

Tags: html, css, performance, background

I have a number of div elements with fixed position backgrounds which are killing performance on my page.  An ideas on how I can improve this?

http://petermankiewich.com/

Comment: You asked the same question only 4 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509138/fixing-scrolling-performance-with-fixed-background-image-on-div. You should not do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is known as 'reflows' and 'repaints'. Each pixel you scroll down, fixed position elements are repainted and is ouch on performance.

You should look into adding `backface-visibility: hidden;` to your fixed position elements.
[source](http://benfrain.com/improving-css-performance-fixed-position-elements/).

Also, look into CSS's `will-change: transform` property, but read about it first as misuse can cost even more in performance.
[source](https://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property)

Anoter [great article here](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) about speeding things up.